# What is this story with insects that want to be eaten?

Tags: story-identification

I remember a story where the captain of the ship was followed around by a colony of rodent-sized insects who lived only to be eaten by him. They all would clamor to be the next one chosen. I think the main characters thought it a little weird.

The captain, IIRC, was a sort of large, Jabba the Hutt-like creature, and the story was in English and may have been part of a novel or a short story.